# Simplest way to assign std::span to std::vector

Tags: c++, std, stdvector, std-span

I wanted to do this

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <span>

struct S
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    void set(std::span<int> _v)
    {
        v = _v;
    }
};
```

But it [does not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/nn8Gxd). What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
v.assign(_v.begin(), _v.end());
```

Comment: Thanks, pretty neat. I was thinking of doing clear() + insert() but this looks better.

Comment: that (`clear` + `insert`) is basically what `assign` does.

Comment: admittedly the `clear` is extra if its in the constructor as you wouldn't expect the any data elements in an empty vector.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`std::vector<T,Allocator>::assign_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign_range) (C++23).

```
v.assign_range(_v);

// or “v.assign(_v.begin(), _v.end());”
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [`std::vector::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) as follows:

```
v.insert(v.begin(), _v.begin(), _v.end());
```

Note that, if the `v` should be emptied before, you should call `v.clear()` before this. However, this allows you to add the span to a specified location in the `v`.

**([See a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/51zcxv))**

Answer (score 1):

The general way to create a new container from any input range is `std::ranges::to()`:

```
        v = _v | std::ranges::to<decltype(v)>();
```

This is more useful for passing a temporary to a function that's more constrained (e.g. it needs a sized or bidirectional range), but it *can* be used for assignment, too (at a short-term cost in memory, since `v`'s contents are not released until after the new container is constructed).